# The idea behind sk-learn's combined grid-search and cross-validated estimators?

Tags: machine-learning, python, cross-validation, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

I am trying incorporate a formal strategy to find the most optimal set hyper-parameters for a machine learning algorithm. I understand you can either do a grid-search or a k-fold cross validation, among many other possible search options.

I came across `scikit-learn`'s grid-search and cross-validated estimators in [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html). It says `by default, the GridSearchCV uses a 3-fold cross-validation.` Seems to me they are combining grid-search and cross-validation together. Does it mean the k-fold validation is done on each grid-search combination? If so, what is the advantage of that? Is it for more stable estimator? And is this combined grid-search and k-fold CV almost always better than just grid-search only or just k-fold CV only in finding the optimal hyper-parameters?

Answer (score 0):

1. GridSearch or [random search](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/bergstra12a/bergstra12a.pdf) concern how you search the hyper-parameter space for hyper-parameter configurations.
2. [k-fold CV, hold out method and so on](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ron_Kohavi/publication/2352264_A_Study_of_Cross-Validation_and_Bootstrap_for_Accuracy_Estimation_and_Model_Selection/links/02e7e51bcc14c5e91c000000.pdf) are approaches for estimation of out of sample performance.

You need to apply both for model selection (gridsearch and k-fold CV are a good choice). :-)

Comment: Or, bayesian HPO instead of grid when the grid is large.